# Illegal conversion exception?

Tags: java, arrays, int, double, counter

I am getting an error message on my code to find the total salary of employee's who are payed $200 + the commission amount. Once all the employee's gross sales are input it is supposed to print out the amount of employee's that fell into each different pay category. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int basePay = 200; //$200 starting amount of pay
    int totalPay = 0; //total amount the employee will receive

    System.out.print("Enter the amount of employees: ");
    int employee = input.nextInt();

    int[]sales = new int[9]; //four different categories

    for(int i = 0; i < employee; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the current employee's gross sales: ");
        int grossSales = input.nextInt();

        totalPay = (int) (basePay + (grossSales * 0.09)); //uses the formula for finding pay, and then casts it to an int

        if(totalPay <= 299.99){
            sales[0]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 399.99){
            sales[1]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 499.99){
            sales[2]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 599.99){
            sales[3]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 699.99){
            sales[4]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 799.99){
            sales[5]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 899.99){
            sales[6]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay <= 999.99){
            sales[7]++;
        }
        else if(totalPay >= 1000){
            sales[8]++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Sales\tAmount of employees");

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ", i * 100, i * 100 + 99.99);
        System.out.print("\t" + sales[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Checking array: " + Arrays.toString(sales));
}
```

Here is the exact error message I am getting:

```
00-Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at chapter7.Sales_comission.main(Sales_comission.java:54)
```

I believe it is something to do with double conversions, but I am not exactly sure what is wrong with it? Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong (it compiles without error)? Also I have tried having only doubles (including the array), but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: I think the complaint may be about applying `%02d` to a double expression, `i * 100 + 99.99`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'd' is for integer, either change it to 'f' or cast the second parameter to integer.

```
 System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ", i * 100, (int)(i * 100 + 99.99));
```

see [Java String Formatter Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details.

Comment: It worked but now it is no longer counting the values correctly.

Comment: You can use "%.2f" to format float/double. i.e. System.out.printf("%02d-%.2f: ", i * 100, i * 100 + 99.99);